# PasswordResetView takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: django, django-forms

```
def password_recover(request):
    print("password_recover")
    return password_reset(request, subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt')
```

So I had that piece of code, that was working on django 1.8.While migrating to django 2.2, i changed that piece of code too the one below

```
def password_recover(request):
        print("password_recover")
        return PasswordResetView(request, subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt')
```

I am getting error takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: `PasswordResetView` is a class-based view. You need to first call the `as_view()` method to return a function, which you can then call. But I don't understand why you're doing this in the first place, rather than calling it directly from your urls.py.

Comment: yeh even when i try PasswordResetView.as_view(request, subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt') i get same error. i already did that

Comment: You can turn a CBV into a function-based view like this: `PasswordResetView.as_view(subject_template_name='registration/password_reset_subject.txt')(request)`, since `as_view` takes the class's initialising arguments and returns a function that can then be called as a usual function-based view. But this is not the usual way to use CBVs. The answer below is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use it like so, the correct example would be:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    subject_template_name = 'registration/password_reset_subject.txt'
```

and in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PasswordResetView.as_view())
]
```

Take a note that `PasswordResetView` is a [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/) and you need to call `.as_view()` method.

Comment: You don't need to define any class attribute except the one you want to override (`subject_template_name`).

Comment: @dirkgroten true, just an example. Thanks for improving!